# passing a list of arrays to native c++

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface, native, managed

I need to pass a list of managed arrays from C# code to native c++ code.
this is the code I am using

```
for (int i = 0; i < Digits->Count; i++)
{
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> ptemp = &(Digits[i]->Digit[0]);
    nativeTemplates.digits.push_back(ptemp);
}
```

I see that the buffers that are passed to the native c++ are garbage.
This is because the buffers are not pinned when the pin_ptr loses scope out of the loop.
with the following code all is well.

```
pin_ptr<unsigned char> ptemp = &(Digits[0]->Digit[0]);
nativeTemplates.digits.push_back(ptemp);

pin_ptr<unsigned char> ptemp1 = &(Digits[1]->Digit[0]);
nativeTemplates.digits.push_back(ptemp1);

pin_ptr<unsigned char> ptemp2 = &(Digits[2]->Digit[0]);
nativeTemplates.digits.push_back(ptemp2);

.
.
.

pin_ptr<unsigned char> ptempn = &(Digits[n]->Digit[0]);
nativeTemplates.digits.push_back(ptempn);
```

My question is how can I perform what I need with out explicitly coding the pinning of each member in the list.

Comment: what is the definition of nativeTemplates.digits?

Comment: It's a vector<unsigned char*>

Comment: maybe you can put the chars in a string(stringbuilder) and pass the string to native code. When a pinning pointer goes out of scope, the object is no longer considered pinned, so if you use pin_ptr, it seems you must stick to this solution.